# Unresolved symbols when linking a program with a library using C++Amp under MSVC++ 2012

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, linker, c++-amp

I am trying to solve the following issue: I've got a library which uses C++Amp. The library compiles without any warnings and the unit-tests indicate that everything is working. I have a QT-based project which is a GUI for this library and here the problems begin. Everytime I am compiling the GUI, in the linking stage a get the following errors:

> widgets.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: unsigned short const * __cdecl Concurrency::accelerator::_Get_device_path(void)const " (_*imp*?_Get_device_path@accelerator@Concurrency@@AEBAPEBGXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'public: static class std::_Future_error_category std::_Future_error_object::_Future_object''(void)" (??__E?_Future_object@?$_Future_error_object@H@std@@2V_Future_error_category@2@A@@YAXXZ)

The library is linked to lib file, not dll.

Same story goes for other object files in the project. Did anyone have a similar problem at the linking stage when using C++Amp. I am sure that it is a very simple problem to solve but at the moment I have no idea how I could do it. Thanks in advance.

**Update**: the same happens when I am trying to include  in the QT project in MSVC++.

Comment: I'm assuming that you get a whole load of these? It looks like you are  not linking the AMP binaries into your QT project.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a lot of them. Actually I have a static lib project (ccilib) and it is a static library (lib file) and the problem occures when I am trying to run my QT project (GUI) which is linked with cci project. How should I link the AMP binaries?

Comment: You have a compiler setting wrong.  You cannot get the code linked until you reset the C/C++, Language, Treat wchar_t as built-in type back to the default.  You will need to use this setting consistently in all your compiled code, including Qt.

Comment: How should I change it for QT? Recompile?

Comment: I set it just as you said and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmya, you cannot possibly rebuild Qt in 15 minutes.  You've worn me out, talk to your team members.  There ought to be a collective memory cell left that remembers why this was done.

Comment: Have you tried pasting the .dll file in the project's Debug folder?

Comment: Solved! It turned out that I needed to set the flag **Treat wchar_t as built-in type** to **Yes** in all of the projects in the solution.

Comment: Could I ask you @HansPassant to answer this question so I can accept it officialy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  __imp_?_Get_device_path@accelerator@Concurrency@@AEBAPEBGXZ
```

Running the undname.exe utility on that string to unmangle the name, I get:

```
  declspec(dllimport) private: 
  unsigned short const * __ptr64 
  __cdecl Concurrency::accelerator::_Get_device_path(void)const __ptr64
```

So it is 64-bit code.  Looking in vc/lib/amd64/vcamp.lib for a closest match, I find:

```
 ?_Get_device_path@accelerator@Concurrency@@AEBAPEB_WXZ
```

Which demangles with undname.exe to:

```
 private: 
 wchar_t const * __ptr64 
 __cdecl Concurrency::accelerator::_Get_device_path(void)const __ptr64
```

Note the discrepancy.  Your function got compiled to return `unsigned short*`, the library function returns `wchar_t*`.  You have a compiler setting wrong.  Project + Properties, C/C++, Language, Treat WChar_t As Built in Type must be set to the default, "Yes".

Comment: I already tried it, but it seems that I get some other QT errors when setting it. This is the error I get: `error C2664: 'QString::fromUtf16' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [10]' to 'const ushort *'
2>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast` 

The error is related to this line of code:
`QMessageBox::information(this, QString::fromUtf16(title), QString::fromUtf16(msg));` 
Let me see it once again.

Comment: You'll need to retrace your steps to figure out why you changed the default.  Having to rebuild the Qt libraries could be necessary, the normal distribution gets this right however so you might have rebuild them already and got it wrong.  This will keep on hurting if you don't fix it, wchar_t is rather a big deal on Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately setting `Treat WChar_t As Built in Type` to "Yes"  didn't work. I am still getting the same linking errors.